# If I Restart the docker, celery worker stops consuming tasks

Tags: python, django, docker, celery, amazon-sqs

I am having weird issue with Celery and Docker. As a broker I am using SQS, it works fine if I clear the docker cache and start the docker engine fresh. but if I rebuild the docker and start it again, celery worker stops consuming tasks.

Worker works fine outside of the container (i.e in my local environment)

Here are the versions I am using.

```
celery[sqs]==5.2.*
django==4.1.*
pycurl==7.44.*
```

my docker-compose

```
  celery_worker:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    command: sh -c "celery -A app.celery:celery_app worker --loglevel=INFO"
    depends_on:
      - api
```